# Go json-rpc returns empty respond

Tags: json, go, rpc, json-rpc

I'm writing a client-server interaction using json-rpc protocol, via Go standard library.
Server side works fine, but i can't get correct respond, i get empty respond.
Respond type is public.

Server side

```golang
func (h *Handler) AddUser(request UserAuthRequest, respond *uuid.UUID) error {
    log.Printf("AddUser: request:%+v", request)
    id := uuid.New()
    respond = &id
    log.Printf("%v", respond)  // prints generated ID
    return nil
}
```

Client side

```golang
var x uuid.UUID
err = client.Call(
    "Handler.AddUser",
    &UserAuthRequest{},
    &x,
)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("bad request: %v", err)
}
log.Printf("res: %+v", x)  // prints 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

How can i get non-empty respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution on quite obvious
Instead of reassign pointer `respond` to `&id`, i need to change value of `*respond`.
So just change line `respond = &id` to `*respond = id`
That's all